# DJANGO RF - Include the SerializerMethodField when nesting a serializer in another serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer on my UserProfile model. It includes a SerializerMethodField "userGlobalPoints" :

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userGlobalPoints = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_userGlobalPoints(self, obj):
        (*** calculation ***)
        return userGlobalPoints

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my Post serializer, I want to nest, for each post, information about the post's author. So I include fields from the UserProfile model (there is a ForeignKey relation in the Post model).

I would like to add the userGlobalPoints field. But I can't figure out how I can nest this field in the serializer. It looks like the usual syntax for nesting a serializer does not work on SerializerMethodField fields.

This is my PostSerializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    authorNickname = serializers.CharField(source='postAuthor.userNickname', read_only=True)

    authorProfileWithGlobalPoints = UserProfileSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['pk','authorNickname','postText', 'postTimestamp', 'authorProfileWithGlobalPoints']
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
Following a clever comment, the issue is not related to the SerializerMethodField. None of the fields of the nested serializer is serialized! I probably made a mistake in nesting the serializer in the reverse relation direction.

So the question does not need any more answers. Thank you all.

**EDIT 2**
The error was not caused by the MethodField. The issue is that I have nested serializers in the reverse direction of their relation. I tried to nest the author in the Post object, I should rather have nested the Post in the Author object. Since then I have changed my logic and it works.
Maybe an administrator could delete this topic, since it does not bring very much value to anybody.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. I tried something similar and nested SerializerMethodField objects work to me. Is `authorProfileWithGlobalPoints` correctly nested without the SerializerMethodField?

Comment: @Pentracchiano You're absolutely right. It's not working without the SerializerMethodField. Following to your answer, I have investigated more and the reason why it does not work is because I'm going in the reverse side of the ForeignKey relation between UserProfile and Post. Thaks a lot, I will edit the question!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting exactly?

Could it be that `authorProfileWithGlobalPoints` is not defined on the Post model? Maybe this solves it, by telling Django what to look for in the model:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    authorProfileWithGlobalPoints = UserProfileSerializer(source='postAuthor', many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['pk','postText', 'postTimestamp', 'authorProfileWithGlobalPoints']
```

Comment: The error was simple: no data serialized by the nested serializer. I have investigated: this is not caused by the MethodField. The issue is that I have nested serializers in the reverse direction of their relation. I tried to nest the author in the Post object, I should rather have nested the Post in the Author object.
Since then I have changed my logic and it works.
Thank you very much for your help !